# Geth Ethereum private network still shows connections with --nodiscover

Tags: go-ethereum

I had reviewed this answer:

[disabled private network is still discovering nodes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28007/disabled-private-network-is-still-discovering-nodes)

But did not see a resolution to my issue.

After typical setup of private network with genesis block init and then startup I see established connections in lsof that geth has made:

https://pastebin.com/9eyF2R8y

though admin.peers shows []

tcpdump on port 30303 shows requests going to outside nodes though no responses come back (only ">" seen not "<").

So what is nodiscover really doing as it seems to be discovering quite a bit?

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue. It appears that `--nodiscover` is just disabling your node from running node-discovering algorithm to find peers to connect, but it doesn't prevent others from discovering and attempting to connect to your node. If you'd like to limit the inbound connection attempts, you could specify `--netrestrict`. 
e.g. `--netrestrict="127.0.0.1/8"`